# Which stud should I mount to if they are different widths?

Tags: drywall, mounting, studs

I'm trying to mount a pull up bar to the studs behind my drywall. The studs are 16" apart, but seem to be of different widths. Specifically, I see a 3.5" stud, 3.5", 2", 2", 3.5". Are these just 2x4s in different orientations? Is there a preference for which I should mount on?

Comment: How are you measuring those widths? If you're doing it with an ultrasonic pinger,  I'd be skeptical of trying to get accurate width measurements from that. If you've opened the wall and looked, that's a different kettle of worms...

Comment: From my part of the country it was "kettle of fish" and "can of worms". But I guess that is probably the subject of a different Stack Exchange site. :^)

Comment: @MichaelKaras Perhaps "Seasoned Advice?"

Comment: I measured with density stub finder. I did measure multiple times at many heights, and the measurement holds across the two stub types for the five stubs, so I'm inclined to believe it's right, though as you say, you never know until you open the wall...

Answer (score 1):

The 3.5" studs are either doubled-up 2x4s, or a sideways 2x4. I would use the 2" studs to mount it on because if the 3.5" studs are sideways, they will be more likely to bow out under load, and a regular 2x4 is more than strong enough to hold body weight.